# Could UI options be provided when editing text in the mobile browser mode?

Tags: feature-request

When writing a new question, some UI options are provided to easily add a hyperlink, image etc.
[image]
However, when using the mobile phone web browser to edit a question or write a new answer, these options are not available in the UI. Hope it could be made available on all StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that UI by switching to full site via the footer. If the full site doesn't look good on your phone, double-check that responsiveness is enabled (also via the footer).

I don't have a link handy, but my recollection is that SE's goal is to keep improving the responsive full site until it's good enough to completely replace the mobile view, and in the meantime they're not significantly investing in the mobile view.

Comment: Ah...never noticed that. Thanks. Turns out, there is a "Desktop site" option in the mobile web browser's menu which does the same thing.